# Loop Dependence analysis for parallel processing

Tags: loops, parallel-processing, parallel.foreach

I am having trouble understanding with what Loop Dependence test following dependence can be revealed.

```
for(k=1;k<N;++k){
  for(j=0;j<4;++j){
      avg[j]=avg[j]+somevar;
  }
}
```

What dependence test would tell me that the outer loop has loop carried memory dependence?